# Callback not working in TensorFlow to stop training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have written a call back which stops training when accuracy becomes 99%. But the problem is I get this error. Sometimes if I resolve this error the call back not get called even though accuracy becomes 100%. The error:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            
            if(logs.get('accuracy') > 0.99):
                
                
               
               self.model.stop_training = True


def train_mnist():
    # Please write your code only where you are indicated.
    # please do not remove # model fitting inline comments.

    # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE

    # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    call = myCallback()
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path=path)
    # YOUR CODE SHOULD START
    x_train = x_train/255
    y_train = y_train/255
    # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
          keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
          keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')
        # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # model fitting
    history = model.fit(# YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
          x_train,y_train,epochs=9,callbacks=[call] )
    # model fitting
    return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]
```

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow are you using?, based on that the answer would change. If < 2.xx, then the tag would be 'acc' instead of 'accuracy'. In             "if(logs.get('accuracy') > 0.99):"
  In anycase, you could experiment with changing this tag.

Comment: It is giving this version print(tf.__version__)          1.14.0

Comment: I changed it now error gone.But i'm unable to stop the training process even after exceeding 0.099 accuracy

Comment: If thats the case,  logs.get('acc') can work. Also do change it here too: model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['acc'])

Comment: I changed it but unable to stop the trainning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two major problems with the above code:

- Getting to 100% accuracy on training set almost always means that your model is overfitting. Thats **BAD**. What you want to do instead is specify the `validation_split=.2` parameter in the `.fit` method, and look for a high accuracy on the validation set.
- What you are trying to build in your custom callback is already done in `keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`, it even has an option to restore to the best overall model over each epoch. And, by default, it is looking for a validation accuracy, not training accuracy, if you have a validation split.

So, here's what you should do:
Stop using custom callbacks, they take some mastery to get to work. Use `EarlyStopping` with `restore_best` instead. [like this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping)
Always use `validation_split` and look for high accuracy in validation set. [Like in this quick example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate).

---

Did using built-in callbacks resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but instead of `logs.get('accuracy')` I did `logs.get('acc')` and it worked.